# How do I parse a JSON scalar type with SmallRye GraphQL Client on Quarkus?

Tags: graphql, quarkus, contentful, smallrye

I have a service using Quarkus that uses SmallRye GraphQL Client to query for Contentful GraphQL API.

Before I explain the problem, I should give a bit of background about Contentful. It is a sort of Headless CMS that allows you to create objects that contain different types of fields. One of these fields is called **rich text**. This type is a complex type that is returned in the GraphQL API as a nested object.

According to their [documentation](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/graphql/#/reference/schema-generation/rich-text) this field is scalar type called JSON and a non-null. Using SmallRye GraphQL Client I was able to get any other field even the nested fields but this one.

For more details on how to set up a GraphQL client on Quarkus, refer to the [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/smallrye-graphql-client).

FYI: the GraphQL field `json` has no subfields so it is not possible to create a nested class containing the fields returned from the response.

Comment: Are you using a dynamic or a typesafe client? If typesafe, doesn't it work if you simply add a `String json` field into the class that represents `ArticleText`?

Comment: Of course, you then probably need to use a Json parser if you wish to work with Json. You get JSON-B automatically in the classpath when using this extension.

Comment: I have tried implementing `JsonbConfigCustomizer` and add my own deserialiser but it seems not to take the bean into consideration. @JanMartiška

Comment: How exactly did you attempt that? I think the client-side library doesn't support plugging in custom deserializers (unless I forgot about that).  That's something that could be useful though, so feel free to report a feature request in smallrye-graphql github repo. But until that is supported, you'll have to deserialize manually, I think.

Comment: Thats a good point you mention because I have used [this way](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-json#mixin-support) to add a custom Jsonb deserializer.

Comment: Ok unless there's some hidden magic that I'm unaware of, this only works for resteasy endpoints, not for graphql clients.